# how to: use AudioManager startBluetoothSco() function in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-recording

If i want to setup the restrictions for the  AudioManager.startBluetoothSco() function where do i do that?
from here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco()

The restrictions are:

• the stream type must be STREAM_VOICE_CALL

•the format must be mono

• the sampling must be 16kHz or 8kHz

The STREAM_VOICE_CALL can be stetup in:

```
AM.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

or

```
AM.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
```

The Mono and the sampling can setup in:

```
audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersizebytes);
```

can anyone think or know deffernt ways?

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided to the Android SDK docs says the following:

"... if a SCO connection is established, the following restrictions apply on audio output streams so that they can be routed to SCO headset:

- the stream type must be STREAM_VOICE_CALL
- the format must be mono
- the sampling must be 16kHz or 8kHz

The following restrictions apply on input streams:

- the format must be mono
- the sampling must be 8kHz"

Your usage of "AudioRecord" is an input stream and does not need to be concerned w/ STREAM_VOICE_CALL:

For "AudioTrack" you would need to do the following when in SCO mode:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, //
8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, //
minBufferSizeInBytes, //
AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

And the following when *NOT* in SCO mode:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, //
8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, //
minBufferSizeInBytes, //
AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Comment: Deeply  sorry for so delayed answer, I almost lost hope and trebled finical so i gave a short try and when it failed i became desperate.But, it was always on my mind to try again.u gave me hope ,your  suggestion was to use AudioTrack as the input , What i really need to know is,What to use as output? .  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem u have to use both like this:one for input and the other for output

```
                    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                                    android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC ,                                                                                SAMPPERSEC,
            channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, buffersizebytes);

        Atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
            SAMPPERSEC,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            audioEncoding,
            buffersizebytes,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```